# Autoupdating software using intranet

Tags: c#, intranet

i searched for the topic but didn't find exactly that kind of problem.

I want to create a C# WinForms software which should run only in intranet. If i change the software afterwards i would like to have the application to look automatically in the network for a newer version. Is a newer version available it should replace the old one. Maybe there is some tool or library to achieve that?

Further Information: The software does not use a database and consists only out of one .exe file. No other stuff or files needed.

I don't want to setup a server or something like that for this task. I want it as simple and clean as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think clickonce may help you. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx for more details

Answer (score 0):

I really like the [updateSystem.NET](http://updatesystem.net)-lib, but which is only available in german. If you can understand the easy API, this is exactly what you are searching for.

[Here](http://updatesystem.net/Help/StepByStep.aspx), you can find a little tutorial, also in german.

Comment: Google chrome can translate this page on the fly, so it may be useful even if you don't understand German.